# Selección de opciones en select con datos de la base de datos

Tags: php, html, sql

Muy buenas chicos, tengo un problemilla, Estoy haciendo un formulario, quiero que en los select, me carguen los datos que tengo en la base de datos. En si me carga, el problema es que me duplica los forms y me salen tropecientos, solo quiero un form y que en cada select salgan todos los datos y no de uno en uno, este es mi código.

```
<?php
include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';

$sql_leer = 'SELECT usuario,apellidos,email FROM usuarios WHERE id';

$gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
$gsnet->execute();

$resultado = $gsnet->fetchAll();
//var_dump($resultado);

//Agregar los datos

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos-dasboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos_web.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mdb.css"> 

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="barra-lateral col-12 col-sm-auto">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu d-flex d-sm-block justify-content-center flex-wrap">
                <a href="../admin/dashboard.php"><i class="icon-home"></i><span>Inicio</span></a>
                    <a href="../admin/reportar.php"><i class="icono icon-attention"></i><span>Reportes a usuario</span></a>
                    <a href="../admin/clasificacionadmin.php"><i class="icono icon-flag"></i><span>Clasificación</span></a>
                    <a href="../admin/comisarios.php"><i class="icon-doc-text"></i><span>Comisarios</span></a>
                    <a href="../admin/publicar.php"><i class="icon-doc-text"></i><span>Publicaciones</span></a>
                    <a href="../php/cerrar.php"><i class="icon-logout"></i><span>Salir</span></a>

                </nav>
            </div>

            <main class="main col">
                <div class="row portafolio">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            <h2 class="titulo">Reportes a pilotos</h2>
                                <p>Envía una alerta y correo al piloto implicado.
                                </p>
                                <div class="card">

<!-- Card body -->
<div class="card-body">

    <!-- Material form register -->
    <form action="envio_alerta.php" method="POST">
    <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <p>Nombre</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected>Elige opción</option>
        <option><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></option> 
      </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      <p>Apellidos</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected><?php echo $dato['apellidos']?></option>
        <option></option> 
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Email</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected><?php echo $dato['email']?>n</option>
        <option></option> 
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Texto</p>
      <div class="form-group z-depth-2">

    <textarea name="alerta"class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
        <div class="text-center py-4 mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect z-depth-3" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Material form register -->

</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>      
    </div>  


    <!-- Usar la CDN requiere acceso a Internet -->
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> -->


    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu condicion **WHERE id'**    esta incompleta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL problema es que abres el bucle antes del Select, por lo que te toma el elemento completo y lo duplica cuantas opciones tienes. Lo que tienes que hacer es abrir un foreach por cada select y hacerlo entre un , de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="envio_alerta.php" method="POST">
        <p>Nombre</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected>Elige opción</option>
        <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></option> 
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      <p>Apellidos</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
      <option selected>Elige opción</option>
       <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option><?php echo $dato['apellidos']?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Email</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
      <option selected>Elige opción</option>
       <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option><?php echo $dato['email']?>n</option>
        <?php endforeach ?> 
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Texto</p>
      <div class="form-group z-depth-2">

    <textarea name="alerta"class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
    </div>

        <div class="text-center py-4 mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect z-depth-3" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

De esa manera te generará las opciones sin duplicarte los select. Quedo atento, espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido!!!!

Comment: Con gusto @IvanInceraMundogamer , si se ha solucionado tu problema por favor marca la pregunta como resuelta

Answer (score 0):

Perdon pero no entiendo. El envio es una sola persona. Porque construyes el FORM de esa manera? Para cada record de la tabla sale un nombre, un apellido y un email. Porque tienes que construir un `select` para cada uno de estos campos. 
Otra cosa que te sugiero, separa el HTML, del PHP. Lo entiendes mejor y es reutilizable.